# Computing Complex Integral to Determine Analytic Continuation of $f(z) = \int_0^\infty {{e^{-zt}} \over {1 + t^2}} dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, analyticity

My question is the following:

> Find the analytic continuation of the function $f(z)$ defined by
>   $$ f(z) = \int_0^\infty {{e^{-zt}} \over {1 + t^2}} dt, \ \ \vert \arg(z) \vert < {1 \over 2}\pi,$$
>   to the domain $\{ z \in \Bbb C \mid -{1 \over 2}\pi < \arg(z) < \pi \}$.

My attempt to do this is by calculating the above integral using Cauchy's Residue Theorem (especially as the previous question had me to just that for a different situation!). I observe that the poles are at $\pm i$. My issue is in determining which contour to use. I can't take a semicircle in either the upper or lower half planes since then the "$-\infty$ to $0$" integral won't converge, and neither will the integral over the semicircle. I have tried using a quarter-circle in the first quadrant, but that gives a similarly unpleasant integral along the imaginary axis.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

**Important note:**

 There is this question here,
[Find the analytic continuation of the $ f(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{exp(-zt)}{1+t^2} dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680156/find-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-fz-int-0-infty-fracexp-zt),
which is entirely the same as my question, however that answer is not using complex variables techniques. I am interested in a complex analysis proof, not one that gives an expression in terms of an infinite sum.

Thanks! :)
Sam

Comment: I'm a beginner in CA. So, the only strategy I can think of is along the lines of the schwartz reflection theorem. Have you tried anything like that ?

Comment: I've actually never heard of such a theorem! =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some definitions:
$$\operatorname{C_i}(x)=-\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\cos t}{t} dt=\gamma +\log x +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x^2)^n}{2n(2n)!},$$
$$\operatorname{S_i}(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t} dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)(2n-1)!}
.$$
Replacing $x$ by $z$, we get $\operatorname{C_i}(z)$ and $\operatorname{S_i}(z)$. $\operatorname{C_i}(z)$ is analytic and single-valued in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$ , $\operatorname{S_i}(z)$ is entire. So
$$G(z)=\operatorname{C_i}(z)\sin z -\operatorname{S_i}(z)\cos z+\frac{\pi}{2}\cos z$$
is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$.
First we evaluate the integral$$f(a) = \int_0^\infty {{e^{-at}} \over {1 + t^2}} dt=\int_0^\infty {{ae^{-x}} \over {x^2 + a^2}} dx
$$for a **real positive** $a$.
Integrate $\varphi (z)=\frac{ae^{-z}}{z^2+a^2}$ along a quarter-circle in the first quadrant, then
$$\int_0^R {{ae^{-x}} \over {x^2 + a^2}} dx+\int_{C_R}\varphi (z)dz-i(PV)\int_0^R \frac{ae^{-iy}}{y^2-a^2}dy=\pi i Res(\varphi , ia)  \tag{1}$$
because $\varphi (z)$ has a simple pole at $z=ia$. We note
$$\lim_{ R\to \infty} \int_{C_R}\varphi (z)dz=0,$$
$$ Res(\varphi , ia)=-\frac{ie^{-ia}}{2},$$
$$(PV)\int_0^\infty \frac{ae^{-iy}}{y^2-a^2}dy=i\operatorname{C_i}(a)\sin a -i\operatorname{S_i}(a)\cos a -\frac{\pi}{2}\sin a.\tag{2}$$
Our technique employed to obtain (2) is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
(PV)\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-iy}}{y-a}dy&=(PV)\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-i(y-a)}\cdot e^{-ia}}{y-a}dy\\
&=(PV)\int_{-a}^a \frac{e^{-it}\cdot e^{-ia}}{t}dt+\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-it}\cdot e^{-ia}}{t}dt\\
&=-2ie^{-ia}\int_0^a \frac{\sin t}{t}dt+\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-it}\cdot e^{-ia}}{t}dt.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore from (1) we have $$f(a)=\operatorname{C_i}(a)\sin a -\operatorname{S_i}(a)\cos a+\frac{\pi}{2}\cos a.$$
Since this holds for all $a>0$, we have $$f(z)=G(z) $$for $z$ with $\operatorname{Re} z>0$.
We know  that $G(z)$ is the analytic continuation of $f(z)$ to the domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$ .

**Addemdum**

Equality (1) should be
$$\int_0^R {{ae^{-x}} \over {x^2 + a^2}} dx+\int_{C_R}\varphi (z)dz+i(PV)\int_0^R \frac{ae^{-iy}}{y^2-a^2}dy=\pi i Res(\varphi , ia)  \tag{1}$$

Details of evaluation of $(PV)\int_0^\infty \frac{ae^{-iy}}{y^2-a^2}dy$:
$$\begin{align}
2\cdot (PV)\int_0^\infty \frac{ae^{-iy}}{y^2-a^2}dy
&=(PV)\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-i(y-a)}\cdot e^{-ia}}{y-a}dy-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-i(y+a)}\cdot e^{ia}}{y+a}dy\\
&=e^{-ia}\left((PV)\int_{-a}^a \frac{e^{-it}}{t}dt+\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-it}}{t}dt\right)-e^{ia}\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-it}}{t}dt\\
&=-2ie^{-ia}\operatorname{S_i}(a)+(e^{-ia}-e^{ia})\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-it}}{t}dt\\
&=-2ie^{-ia}\operatorname{S_i}(a)+2i\left(\operatorname{C_i}(a)+i\int_a^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right)\sin a\\
&=-2ie^{-ia}\operatorname{S_i}(a)+2i\operatorname{C_i}(a)\sin a-2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\operatorname{S_i}(a)\right)\sin a\\
&=-2i\operatorname{S_i}(a)\cos a+2i\operatorname{C_i}(a)\sin a-\pi \sin a\\
(PV)\int_0^\infty \frac{ae^{-iy}}{y^2-a^2}dy&=-i\operatorname{S_i}(a)\cos a+i\operatorname{C_i}(a)\sin a-\frac{\pi}{2} \sin a
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok yeah, I follow this, apart from one part: After equation $(2)$, the squares disappear from the integral from which we're taking the principle value. I realise that $y^2 - a^2 = (y-a)(y+a)$, and you're then looking at $a>0$, so $y+a \neq 0$ for $y \in [0, \infty)$, so no pole; this doesn't mean that we can just ditch the $1/(y+a)$ factor, does it?

Comment: Also, I can't quite do it in my head without thinking about it really hard, but do the various ${1 \over 2}\pi\sin(a)$ and similar terms all just combine with the $-{1 \over 2}i e^{-ia}$ terms, and you've just left out the tedious algebra?

Comment: I will write details in Addendum.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) - the only thing I would say is about the minus sign you changed to plus in $(1)$: surely it is a minus? You start at $(0,0)$, go to $(R,0)$, arc around to $(0,R)$, then come down to $(0,0)$ to end; so the PV integral is $\int_R^0 = - \int_0^R$?

Comment: Yes, we come down from $(0, R)$ to $(0, 0)$. So the part $\int _R^0$ is $\int_R^0 \frac{ae^{-iy}}{(iy)^2+a^2}idy$,which equals to $i\int_R^0 \frac{ae^{-iy}}{-y^2+a^2}dy=i\int_0^R \frac{ae^{-iy}}{y^2-a^2}dy$. Thus the sign should be $+$.

Comment: Ah yes, excellent point. Thanks very much for your help! :)

Comment: I'm actually wondering: Also the expression $$f(a) = \int_0^\infty {{ae^{-x}} \over {x^2 + a^2}} dx$$ is well defined for all values of $a\in {\mathbb C}$ except $a=-i\infty..i\infty$, so what is the problem with this expression? Is it because the 2 regions are not connected?

Comment: @Diger  - Of course the expression 
$$f(a) = \int_0^\infty {{ae^{-x}} \over {x^2 + a^2}} dx\quad (\operatorname{Re }a>0)$$
is well defined and analytic in the region $\operatorname{Re }a>0$.
Also
$$g(a) = \int_0^\infty {{ae^{-x}} \over {x^2 + a^2}} dx\quad (\operatorname{Re }a<0)$$
is analytic in $\operatorname{Re }a<0$.
But $f$ and $g$ are different functions. The analytic continuation of $f$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$ is not equal to $g$, since $f$ has a logarithmic singularity at the origin.